# read.excel function not recognizing sheetname

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I am trying to copy a column from an excel sheet into an array using pandas but am getting the following error:

```
read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheetname'
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Processed_Results_MO.xslx', sheetname='25%')

my_array = df['Methane Output (GJ/y)'].toarray()
```

Comment: It's supposed to be [`sheet_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is called 'sheet_name' so your function would be

```
df = pd.read_excel('Processed_Results_MO.xslx', sheet_name='25%')
```

Comment: This merits a vote-to-close as a typo, not an answer then, I think.